# Function to check prime according to specfic instructions

Tags: python

I have to create a function according to some specific instructions. It is designed to check if a number is prime or not. I know there are different ways to do this, and I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to programming.

Anyways, here are the instructions (pseudocode):

```
Function isPrime(n)  
if n=1 then return false  
else  
if n<4 then return true #2 and 3 are prime  
else  
if n mod 2=0 then return false  
else  
if n<9 then return true #we have already excluded 4,6 and 8.  
else  
if n mod 3=0 then return false  
else  
r=floor( sqrt(n) ) #sqrt(n) rounded to the greatest integer r so that r*r<=n  
f=5  
while f<=r  
if n mod f=0 then return false (and step out of the function)  
if n mod(f+2)=0 then return false (and step out of the function)  
f=f+6  
endwhile  
return true (in all other cases)  
End Function
```

and here is my code so far: (Edited for correct indentation)

```
def isrime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n < 4:
        return True
    elif n & 2 == 0:
        return False
    elif n<9:
        return True
    elif n %3 == 0:
        return False
    ????? (Don't know what to write)
    else:
        return True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `2 & 2 == 0` is `False`; perhaps you didn't want to use bitwise AND there?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You've been given  detailed pseudo code, what element of its implementation are you struggling with?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: everything after `n mod 3=0`, apparently.

Comment: umm maybe typo but your code says def isrime(n) should it be isprime(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 3:
        if n <= 1:
            return False
        return True
    if not n%2 or not n%3:
        return False
    for i in range(5, int(n**0.5) + 1, 6):   
        if not n%i or not n%(i + 2):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n < 4:
        return True
    elif n % 2 == 0: # needs modulo not &
        return False
    elif n < 9:
        return True
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        r = n**.5  
        f = 5
        while f <= r:
            if n % f== 0:
                return False #(and step out of the function)
            if n % (f+2)== 0:
                return False# (and step out of the function)
            f+=6
        return True
```